# SAXNotRecognizedException for feature 'http://apache.org/xml/features/standard-uri-conformant'

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, saxparser

Anyone know why I'm hitting below exception for the following code. I'm using Java 6.

```
final XMLReader reader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
reader.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", doValidate);
reader.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema", doValidate);
reader.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/standard-uri-conformant", doValidate);


org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: Feature 'http://apache.org/xml/features/standard-uri-conformant' is not recognized
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found solution:

Added xercesImpl 2.9.1 to my classpath instead of using the internal Java 6 bundled version of Xerces.

Comment: I had the same issue when i switched from JDK 6 to JDK 8, this solution works.

Answer (score 1):

**Got this issue while doing Integration of Spring and Rest Webservice Jersey**

### Solution

**Removed the following jars**
xerces-2.6.2.jar
xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar
xml-apis.jar

**Added**

jaxp-api-1.4.2.jar